# Cannot start JSF application with Omnifaces 2.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

I want to use Onmifaces 2.3 with JSF 2.2.13.

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1208</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- We need this to send e-mails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/tomcat-test">
    <Resource
        name="BeanManager"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"
    />
</Context>
```

When I try to start Tomcat I get:

```
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fplamen%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4475745058534067256.xml&path=/Crm_site
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /Crm_site but context failed to start
```

Probably this is caused by wrong configuration in web.xml or context.xml.
I tried to place OmniFaces 2.3 JAR file in /WEB-INF/lib but the result isthe same.
How I can fix this?

Comment: What is the root cause of the fail?

Comment: In Tomcat log file I get `16-May-2016 05:28:55.975 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager
`

Comment: Looks like I don't have CDI enabled. I have added in my POM dependency and beans.xml with htis content <beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>

Comment: What is the message of the root cause? (the `IllegalArgumentException` one).

Comment: This is the complete log file: http://pastebin.com/HjPL87Qs

Comment: At this point it is easier to use TomEE